# How to initialise a block matrix with the same matrices as elements?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given a 2x2 matrix `r = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]], dtype=complex)`, how do I create a block matrix such that I get N `r` as its entries so that I get

```
np.array([r, r,..., r, r])
```

Is there like a `np.something(r, 5)` so that it gives `np.array([r, r, r, r, r])`?

Comment: That array would have shape `(n,2,2)`.  Is that what you want?  `r[None,:,:].repeat(n,0)` will make a new array of that shape with `r` repeated `n` times on the new first axis.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. And out of all 6 methods(2 here and 4 from the linked post), yours is actually the fastest for big `n` :) If you post your comment as an official solution then I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Oops actually turns out @Divakar 's `np.broadcast_to(r,(n,)+r.shape)` is even quicker, and doesn't slow down if `n` is 100000 say. I'll still accept your answer :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array` again to get what you want.
One way of doing this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
r = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]], dtype=complex)

samples = 5
a = np.array([r]*samples)
print(a.shape) # (samples, 2, 2) = (5, 2, 2)
print(a[0])    # array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j], [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])
```

To scale or speed it up, you may want to use the following:

```
import numpy as np
n_samples = 10000
b = np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, :, :], n_samples, axis=0)
```

Comment: Your way is what I want but is actually slow as you scale it up. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: @DarrenNg I have updated the answer. I hope it can resolve your issue.